Customize default Account Pages for Blazer Server with Interactivity
I am fairly new to blazor ecosystem and have a requirement to modify the default registration to include role for the user. This could be a simple radio but they want selectable cards.
I understand default registration is statically rendered and I cannot set rendermode InteractiveServer. To overcome this I have created a new component and set it as an interactive component.
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<div class="flex space-x-4">
    <div @onclick="@(() => SelectRole("Customer"))"
         class="@GetRoleClass("Customer") cursor-pointer p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center transition">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Customer" class="mb-2" />
        <p class="font-bold">Customer</p>
        <p class="text-sm text-gray-600">Register as a customer to access our products and services.</p>
    </div>
    <div @onclick="@(() => SelectRole("Vendor"))"
         class="@GetRoleClass("Vendor") cursor-pointer p-4 rounded-lg shadow-md flex-1 flex flex-col items-center justify-center transition">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="Vendor" class="mb-2" />
        <p class="font-bold">Vendor</p>
        <p class="text-sm text-gray-600">Register as a vendor to sell your products and services.</p>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<string> OnRoleSelected { get; set; }

    private string? SelectedRole { get; set; }

    private async void  SelectRole(string role)
    {
        SelectedRole = role;
        await OnRoleSelected.InvokeAsync(role);
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private string GetRoleClass(string role) =>
        (SelectedRole == role) ? "border-2 border-blue-500 bg-blue-100" : "border border-gray-300";
}

I use it in default registration page as
<div class="pt-4 mb-4">
                @Input.Role
                    <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold mb-2">Select your role</h3>
                    <RegisterationRoleSelect OnRoleSelected="SelectRole"/>
                    <ValidationMessage For="() => Input.Role" class="text-sm text-red-600 mt-2" />
                </div>

 private async Task SelectRole(string role)
    {
        Input.Role  = role;
        await Task.Yield();
        StateHasChanged();
    }

The resulting form interaction works fine and function in child component is called. however, invoke function does not trigger function in parent. I understand this could be because page is statically rendered and its not waiting for any events.
What is the way around this?
UPDATE:
I am using .net 8
Here is my app.razor
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="h-full ">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:wght@400;500;700&family=Sarala:wght@400;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tailwind.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
   
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.9.6/lottie.min.js"></script>
    <HeadOutlet />
</head>

<body class="h-full">
    <Routes />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="js/googlePlaces.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.App = {
            stripe: {
                PublishableKey: '@Configuration["Stripe:PublishableKey"]'
            }
        };</script>
    <script src="js/StripeSetup.js?v=1.5"></script>




</body>

</html>


Please share your _Host.cshtml file ?

@JasonPan i do not have that file but App.razor which i have included

Use <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" /> instead of <Routes />. in App.razor file.

Please let me know if it works for you, thanks

@JasonPan no didnt do the trick. This is what i have found so far Blazor's built-in authentication uses Razor Pages for the Identity scaffolding, which aren’t affected by Blazor’s rendermode. the Blazor app unload and redirects to the Register razor page. after registration, and setting the authentication cookie, the identity page redirects back to the Blazor app, which is reloaded and has access to the identity context loaded from the cookie.

Hi Afnan, could you create a brand new project which can reproduce the issue for us? Please hide your sensitive information if any. I am willing to  check it, thanks for your patience.
